# showing google map on second page

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I am using google maps in my asp.net project. When I type some address, i get suggestions, I pick one of them and map is shown related to that address. This works fine. But I want that user types address in a custom textbox on page 1 and i take that input and populate maps textbox on page 2 as well as show map on page 2 related to address.

here is how I am doing it

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Empty the value on page load
    $("#formattedAddress").val("");
    // variable to indicate whether or not enter has been pressed on the input
    var enterPressedInForm = false;

    var input = document.getElementById("inputName");
    var options = {
      componentRestrictions: {country: 'uk'}
    };
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    $("#formName").submit(function(e) {
        // Only submit the form if information has been stored in our hidden input
        return $("#formattedAddress").val().length > 0;
    });

    $("#inputName").bind("keypress", function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            // Note that simply triggering the 'place_changed' event in here would not suffice, as this would just create an object with the name as typed in the input field, and no other information, as that has still not been retrieved at this point.

            // We change this variable to indicate that enter has been pressed in our input field
            enterPressedInForm = true;
        }
    });

    // This event seems to fire twice when pressing enter on a search result. The first time getPlace() is undefined, and the next time it has the data. This is why the following logic has been added.
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        // If getPlace() is not undefined (so if it exists), store the formatted_address (or whatever data is relevant to you) in the hidden input.
        if(autocomplete.getPlace() !== undefined) {
            $("#formattedAddress").val(autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address);
        }
        // If enter has been pressed, submit the form.
        if(enterPressedInForm) {
            $("#formName").submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Answer (score 0):

You can send variables to other pages (or the same page) with the hashtag.  Anything to the right hand side of the # is ignored by the server, but can be read/set by javascript.

Like on page 1 you have

```
<a href="page2.htm#25">25</a>
<a href="page2.htm#50">50</a>
```

This value can be read by page2, like this:

```
var pos = location.hash.substr(1);
```

---

Here is an example with your form

page1.htm

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Page 1 - type address</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $('#formName').on('submit', function(e) {
      // read address
      var address = $('#formattedAddress').val();
      // add hash to page 2
      window.location = 'page2.htm#' + address;
      // prevent real submit
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="formName">
    <input id="formattedAddress" placeholder="Enter address"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.htm

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Page 2 - populate map</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    if(location.hash) {
      var address = location.hash.substr(1);
      $('#test').html(address);
    }
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Tell me if you have difficulties applying this to a Google Maps webpage. 
Try out passing coordinates to page2.

like "page2.htm#50.24/4.45"  =>

```
var variables = location.hash.substr(1);
var position = variables.split('/');
var lat = Number(position[0]);
var lng = Number(position[1]);
```

Or pass the search string.  That should work too.